# "for" loop does not iterate the way I want

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to get the name and jersey number of 3 hockey players from the user. I then make an object from my created class called HockeyPlayer with the data I have. I then put it into the array. The second iteration does not work. Please help! Thank you in advance.

```
ArrayList<HockeyPlayer> array = new ArrayList<HockeyPlayer>();

//For loop to input names
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{   
    System.out.print("Enter name of Player " + i +":");
    startName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter jersey number of Player " + i +":");
    playNum = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Make objects and add to array
    HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer(startName, playNum);
    array.add(p);
}
keyboard.close();
```

Comment: Sorry i'm relatively new to programming and this site. What do you mean any exception?

Comment: any error in your console / log

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at HockeyTester.main(HockeyTester.java:28)

Comment: `java.util.InputMismatchException`. It seems that you're not entering a number (`keyboard.nextInt()` expects an integer, but it gets something else)

Comment: Ah yes. My intention is for it to ask the name first, then the number. When I run it the first iteration is fine, but the second one displays "Enter name of Player 1:Enter jersey number of Player 1:" on the same line.

Comment: @BrandyAu I think I know why. Lemme write up the answer real quick.

Comment: @home just trying to help

Comment: @John: NP, but code should always be posted in the question itself...

Comment: @Brandy Au please check your mail

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that in every iteration of your loop, you make a call to `nextLine()`, then a call to `nextInt()`, but after you make the call to `nextInt()`, the newline character has not been read. Basically, if the input is something like

```
First Player Name
1
Second Player Name
2
```

then, after the first iteration of your loop, the `Scanner` has just finished reading in the `1`, but not the newline right after it. Hence, in the second iteration, the `nextLine()` deals with the newline after `1`, but *only* that newline. Then, the `nextInt()` call will try to turn `Second` into an `int`, and throws the `InputMismatchException`.

Common ways of going around it are to either put another `nextLine()` call right after the call to `nextInt()` (and just throw away this extra newline), or to just read in the line with the number all at once with a call to `nextLine()`, and parse out the `int` using `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: Dennis, wow! Using the nextLine call really worked. Thank you so much. But I've actually discovered another problem. I'm trying to print out the data using an "enhanced-for loop" but it's not coming out the way I want.

for(HockeyPlayer val : array)
  {
   System.out.println("The players are:");
   System.out.println(val);
  }

Comment: Lemme guess, you want to print out "The players are:", then each of the players' names?

Comment: Exactly, on different lines with their numbers as well. So an example:

Brandy 33

John 21

Comment: Then pull `System.out.println("The players are:")` out of the loop, and print player information inside the loop. Tweak the whitespace however you want.

Comment: Also, please don't edit questions to deal with a completely different issue. If you end up with substantial problems getting your pretty printing the way you want, post a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dennis, you're awesome. And sorry about the editing!

Answer (score 2):

From [InputMismatchException's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) JavaDoc:

Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

It seems that you entered a string whereas nextInt() expects an integer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I want it to ask for a string first, then ask for an int. I have no idea why it wants the int first.

Answer (score 0):

If by second iteration you mean the second `for`, you probably have to override your `HockeyPlayer.toString()` method.

```
public String toString() {
  return name+" "+startNum;
}
```

Comment: In the comments, she mentions that she was getting an `InputMismatchException` in the first loop. After she fixed the original issue, she said she was having issues printing out the information the way she wanted, and only then was the question edited to have the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your keyboard variable is of type java.util.Scanner. If that is true then you need to call keybord.reset() at the end of loop.

Your problem is that keyboard.nextInt() does not consumes end of line which is produced when you hit enter. This end of line character is responsible for your exceptions.

This code works:

```
        HockeyPlayer [] hArr = new HockeyPlayer[3];

        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {   
            String startName = "";
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int playNum = 0;

            System.out.print("Enter name of Player " + i +":");
            startName = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter jersey number of Player " + i +":");
            playNum = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.reset();

            HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer(startName, playNum);
            hArr[i] = p;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good to go with:

```
int playNum = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```